# Extract class from assembly in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

Is it possible to extract a class from an assembly created with Reflection.Emit and save it physically to a directory?

I would like to use this manipulation to generate projects dynamically with specific content (classes, methods ...).

Is there a way to save dynamic classes with code without need for an external tool to decompile them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you pass in `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave` or `AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save` when you call [`AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737438(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can use the [`Save` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zwdfdeh(v=vs.110).aspx) to write it to disk - very useful for running it through [`Peverify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool) to see what you've done wrong :)

Note that this saves the IL - not C# source code, so you would still need to decompile them. If you want C# source code without decompiling, then you would need to *generate* C# source code as your origin - presumably passing it through Roslyn or `CSharpCodeProvider` to get the IL.

Note: not all operations are valid when used in this way - if you are skipping accessibility checks, for example, to access non-public members of types outside of your control. This is allowed in some runtime-only scenarios, but is not reliable in assemblies loaded from disk. Similarly, a lot of things are possible in IL that have no direct C# equivalent.